# Entity Framework and Multiple DB versions

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

We use Entity Framework to get data from a Dynamics GP database for displaying a website.
As time goes on and fields in the database are added, we have a problem that EF needs to be updated with the new fields in the tables.  Of course this has the side effect that our website will only support the newest version of our DB.  Since our customers have wildly different versions of the db in the field, it makes it difficult to manage the EF to support all of those different versions.

In LinqToSql you could omit added fields that we didn't care about in the website or lazy load them.  In EF, you get errors when you try this.  Any ideas on how to do this without having to build different versions of the edmx for different versions of the db?

Thanks!

Comment: Would you be opposed to automatically upgrading user databases (possibly using migrations) so they do have the latest version?

Comment: Bring all the databases up to the latest version?

Comment: It isn't much to do with this, however the problem is mainly on columns that is changed in their definition or removing columns? Added columns in a database should not affect it. Can you provide any error messages/exceptions you're getting?

Comment: We can't upgrade their db's until they upgrade the corresponding software version (the Dynamics GP software)